# Firewall Rule update through backend code

Tags: c#, vbscript, command-line-arguments

I want to update firewall rule through my C# code.I created VB Script(which takes parameter as input) which works fine . But when I call same script through C# code firewall rule is not updated.

Please find my code

VB Script:

```
option explicit

' Create the Shell object
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Create the FwPolicy2 object.
Dim fwPolicy2
Set fwPolicy2 = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2")

' Get the Rules object
Dim RulesObject
Set RulesObject = fwPolicy2.Rules

Dim Arg
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments

Dim rule
'Set NewRule=Nothing
Set rule = CreateObject("HNetCfg.FWRule")

For Each rule In Rulesobject
    if rule.Name = "some rule" then
        rule.RemoteAddresses = Arg(0)
        exit for
    end if
next
```

C# method :

```
 string scriptName = @"full path";
                ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();
                ps.FileName = "cscript.exe";
                ps.Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" \"{1}\"", scriptName, IPRange);
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo = ps;
                p.Start();
                p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed double quotes from Argument list then it worked as expected .

```
 ps.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", scriptName, IPRange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using VBScript to do this looks convoluted to me. Consider using C# directly with `netsh` like this:

```
// Example firewall rule with settings
var exampleFirewallRuleName = "My Rule";
var newRemoteIpAddresses = "127.0.0.1,0.0.0.0,8.8.8.8"; // New list of remote addresses

using (var p = new Process())
{
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("advfirewall firewall set rule name=\"{0}\" new remoteip={1}", 
        exampleFirewallRuleName, newRemoteIpAddresses);

    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}

// Run this command in dos prompt to validate:
// netsh advfirewall firewall show rule name="My Rule"
```